# Один контейнер убивает другой

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Я запускаю на одной тачке несколько контейнеров. Эти контейнеры запускаются с помощью двух различных `docker-compose`. Они являются копияпи с той лишь разницей, что запускаются с различными переменными окружения. При этом, возникает проблема, когда запускается один контейнер, другой падает с `deploy_storage-api_1 exited with code 137`. Насколько я понял, возникает проблема с памятью в `runtime`. Но как в реальности понять, что произошло, я не знаю. Я пробовал выставлять ресурсы в `docker-compose`, но как оказалось, этот функционал не поддерживается без `swarm`. Подскажите, как решить эту проблему? Можно ли это сделать без `swarm`? Также отмечу, что на тачке крутится ещё 5-6 контейнеров.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS BUILD

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install make
RUN apt-get install -y python3.7 python3-pip
RUN python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apt-get install -y git

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN PIP=pip PYTHON=python3.7 make deps
CMD PIP=pip PYTHON=python3.7 make run
```

**env-1**

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://xxx:yyy@a.b.c/bbb
PORT=5001
EVE_USER=aaa
EVE_PASSWORD=zzz
```

**env-2**

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://ppp:lll@a.b.c/fff
PORT=5000
EVE_USER=www
EVE_PASSWORD=mmm
```

**docker-compose-1**

```
version: '2'
services:
  storage-api:
    restart: always
    environment:
        - ENV_FILE=.deploy/.envs/stage.env
    build:
        context: ..
        dockerfile: .deploy/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
        - ..:/app
    mem_limit: 10240m
```

**docker-compose-2**

```
version: '2'
services:
  storage-api:
    restart: always
    environment:
        - ENV_FILE=.deploy/.envs/prod.env
    build:
        context: ..
        dockerfile: .deploy/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - "5001:5001"
    volumes:
        - ..:/app
    mem_limit: 1024m
```

**Log-1**

```
eurvanov@grader-services-2:~/grader-storage$ sudo docker-compose -f .deploy/docker-compose.stage.yml up
Recreating deploy_storage-api_1 ...
Recreating deploy_storage-api_1 ... done
Attaching to deploy_storage-api_1
storage-api_1  | storage starting...
storage-api_1  | PYTHONPATH=. ENV_FILE=.deploy/.envs/stage.env
storage-api_1  |
storage-api_1  | PYTHONPATH=. ENV_FILE=.deploy/.envs/stage.env python3.7 app.py
storage-api_1  | 2019-10-21 18:55:55,083 INFO [root] [in app.py    :<module>            :17   ]: port: 5000
storage-api_1  |
storage-api_1  |  * Serving Flask app "eve" (lazy loading)
storage-api_1  |  * Environment: production
storage-api_1  |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
storage-api_1  |    Use a production WSGI server instead.
storage-api_1  |  * Debug mode: off
storage-api_1  | 2019-10-21 18:55:55,105 INFO [werkzeug] [in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/_internal.py:_log                :122  ]:  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

**Log-2**

```
eurvanov@grader-services-2:~/grader-storage$ sudo docker-compose -f .deploy/docker-compose.prod.yml up
Recreating deploy_storage-api_1 ...
Recreating deploy_storage-api_1 ... done
Attaching to deploy_storage-api_1
storage-api_1  | storage starting...
storage-api_1  | PYTHONPATH=. ENV_FILE=.deploy/.envs/prod.env
storage-api_1  |
storage-api_1  | PYTHONPATH=. ENV_FILE=.deploy/.envs/prod.env python3.7 app.py
storage-api_1  | 2019-10-21 18:55:37,039 INFO [root] [in app.py    :<module>            :17   ]: port: 5001
storage-api_1  |
storage-api_1  |  * Serving Flask app "eve" (lazy loading)
storage-api_1  |  * Environment: production
storage-api_1  |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
storage-api_1  |    Use a production WSGI server instead.
storage-api_1  |  * Debug mode: off
storage-api_1  | 2019-10-21 18:55:37,061 INFO [werkzeug] [in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/_internal.py:_log                :122  ]:  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5001/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
deploy_storage-api_1 exited with code 137
eurvanov@grader-services-2:~/grader-storage$
```

Comment: В контейнерах порты используются? Может они конфликтуют

Comment: @E1mir спасибо за совет, гляну

Comment: @E1mir порты разные

Comment: приведи лог запуска

Comment: @Темкатоже добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение очень простое. Два контейнера с одинаковым названием могут убивать друг друга. При этом, этом, в одном случае они друг друга убивают. В другом, эквивалентном -- нет. Почему так происходит, я не выяснил. Поэтому задал отдельный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1037164/docker-engine-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC). Решение такое: делать разные названия, Чтобы не было пересечений.