# docker engine не убивает контейнеры с одинаковым названием

Tags: docker, docker-compose

В рамках [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1036823/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9/1037161#1037161) выяснил, что одинаковые имена для контейнеров -- плохо. Вроде бы docker engine должен такие вещи решать путём принудительного завершения одного из. Но это происходит не всегда. Вопрос -- почему?

В этом случае завершение происходит:

```
eurvanov@grader-services-2:~/grader-storage/.deploy$ cat docker-compose.stage.yml 
version: '2'
services:
    storage-api-stage:
        restart: always
        environment:
            - ENV_FILE=.deploy/.envs/stage.env
        build:
            context: ..
            dockerfile: .deploy/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        volumes:
            - ..:/app
eurvanov@grader-services-2:~/grader-storage/.deploy$ cat docker-compose.prod.yml 
version: '2'
services:
    storage-api-prod:
        restart: always
        environment:
            - ENV_FILE=.deploy/.envs/prod.env
        build:
            context: ..
            dockerfile: .deploy/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "5001:5001"
        volumes:
            - ..:/app
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS BUILD

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install make
RUN apt-get install -y python3.7 python3-pip
RUN python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apt-get install -y git

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN PIP=pip PYTHON=python3.7 make deps
CMD PIP=pip PYTHON=python3.7 make run
```

В этом случае -- нет:

```
eurvanov@grader-services-2:~/crelise$ cat docker-compose.stage.yml 
version: '3'

services:
    crelise:
        restart: always
        network_mode: host
        environment:
            - ENV_FILE=.envs/stage.env
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/app
    tproxy:
        image:
            dperson/torproxy
        restart: always
        ports:
          - 8118:8118
          - 9050:9050eurvanov@grader-services-2:~/crelise$ cat docker-compose.prod.yml 
version: '3'

services:
    crelise:
        restart: always
        network_mode: host
        environment:
            - ENV_FILE=.envs/prod.env
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/app
    tproxy:
        image:
            dperson/torproxy
        restart: always
        ports:
          - 8119:8118
          - 9051:9050eurvanov@grader-services-2:~/crelise$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS BUILD

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install make
RUN apt-get install -y python3.7 python3-pip
RUN python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apt-get install -y git

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN PIP=pip PYTHON=python3.7 make deps
CMD PIP=pip PYTHON=python3.7 make run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker compose использует в качестве имени проекта (префикса для имени контейнера) имя папки, из которой он был запущен. Если вы запускаете compose из папки с тем же именем - он считает старый контейнер с тем же именем устаревшей копией для того же проекта и убивает его (если посчитает, что актуальная копия должна отличаться по переменным окружения, например). Если запускаете из папки с другим именем - все ок, это отдельный проект, он с первым никак не пересекается, контейнеры в нем отслеживаются независимо.

Имя проекта можно задать [через параметр -p или через переменную окружения](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/). Если у вас два реально независимых окружения - лучше в обоих задать имя проекта явно, а не надеятся на разные имена папок.

Comment: Называть какждый сервис в compose уникальным именем норм идея?

Comment: @hedgehogues сервисы и так должны называться уникально. но если это один и тот же сервис, но в разных окружениях (prod / staging) - то он должен называться одинаково, но быть задеплоен с разными project name